# sftp bookmarks - programs to open remote sftp files

Tags: ssh, gedit, filemanager, sublime-text, sftp

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 64 bit.
In Nautilus there are some sftp bookmarks to connecting to a remote server.
My editor installed are Gedit, Leafpad and LibreOffice.

The problem is that to open a simple .txt file situated in the my PC I can use the program I want (also if isn't the appropriate program), but instead to open a files situated in the sftp location (browsing them with nautilus by clicking on the bookmark) I can succesful use only Gedit or LibreOffice. Any other program I use to open those files (eg. Leafpad) it open the program but with an empty and unnamed new document (no error occurs).

Also if I first open Leafpad, when I try to save the new file it doesn't show me the sftp locations in the "save as... window" under the "resources" panel:

[image: Leafpad]

If I do the same with Gedit it show me all sftp bookmarks and it save successful the file in the remote location.

If I do the same with another one editor (such as SublimeText3) it show me all sftp bookmarks, I choose the desired destination when save the file in the remote location, but when clicking on the "save" button the window stop responding (the button appear still pressed) and after some seconds the editor crashes and self-close. Then appear the window "the application closes unexpectedly" with these informations:

[image: error info]

How can I allow SublimeText3 or Leafpad to open/modify/save sftp files?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution founded in the italian Ubuntu-it forum:
http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=607760

The solution is to use **sshfs**.